# Error while uploading files to FTP--(ftplib.error_reply: 226 Transfer complete. 0 bytes transferred. 0 bps.)

Tags: python-3.x, ftplib

I am trying to upload multiple files on a FTP location. The code worked perfectly fine but has started throwing error now.

Code used:

```
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.com")
ftp.login('ID', 'PWD')
ftp.cwd("/dir")# ftp directory
fileList=[list] # A dynamic list of pdf files to be uploaded.

for i in fileList:
    filename=i+'.pdf'
    print(filename)
    with open('C:\myfilespath\' + filename,'rb') as f_upload:
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename,f_upload)
ftp.quit()
ftp.close()
```

Error received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/mypath.py", line 13, in <module>
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename,f_upload)
  File "C:\mypath\Lib\ftplib.py", line 502, in storbinary
    with self.transfercmd(cmd, rest) as conn:
  File "C:\mypath\Lib\ftplib.py", line 397, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\\mypath\Lib\ftplib.py", line 357, in ntransfercmd
    host, port = self.makepasv()
  File "C:\\mypath\Lib\ftplib.py", line 335, in makepasv
    host, port = parse227(self.sendcmd('PASV'))
  File "C:\\mypath\Lib\ftplib.py", line 843, in parse227
    raise error_reply(resp)
ftplib.error_reply: 226 Transfer complete. 0 bytes transferred. 0 bps.
```

A typical behaviour noticed is that on the first few runs this works perfectly but then starts throwing error.